# Python 3.6.3: Is there a method in the turtle library that does the same thing as root.after?

Tags: python, python-3.6, turtle-graphics

In python, I am making a turtle program and I need to loop a function, I wouldn't use `def n():#code; time.sleep(time); n()` as I am sure it would raise a `RecursionError` soon enough, due to the syntax.

I soon learnt of the `root.after` syntax for `tkinter`.

However, I am looking for the same syntax for the turtle library. I have checked on the internet several times but no luck so far.

Is there any function in the turtle library that would meet my needs?

Comment: It's best to avoid `time.sleep` in GUI code, since it puts _everything_ to sleep. Instead use [`turtle.delay`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay). And yes, it's good to avoid recursion; you should be able to use a simple `while` loop here instead. FWIW, the turtle module runs on top of Tkinter: turtle graphics are rendered on a Tkinter Canvas, and it's possible to use Tkinter methods in turtle via [`turtle.getcanvas()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.getcanvas) if you _really_ need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about?

```
turtle.ontimer(fun, t=0)
```

Parameters: 
fun – a function with no arguments
t – a number >= 0

https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer

Comment: Sounds good to me: this is turtle's equivalent to the Tkinter `.after` method.