# Python turtle - pause execution while listening for keypress

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, listen

I want to program a turtle to move on every second, based on the user pressing the arrow keys.

How do I pause the turtle movement while still listening for key presses?

If I use `sleep()`, the whole program pauses and it no longer listens for key presses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286474/python-3-6-3-is-there-a-method-in-the-turtle-library-that-does-the-same-thing-a

Comment: Thanks - ontimer did exactly what I wanted - once I'd figured out that it has to go inside the function it calls!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.6.3: Is there a method in the turtle library that does the same thing as root.after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286474/python-3-6-3-is-there-a-method-in-the-turtle-library-that-does-the-same-thing-a)